# Не работает Opencv_traincascade

Tags: opencv, машинное-обучение

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenCV\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin\Opencv_traincascade.exe" -data c:\Projects\AdaBoost2\trained -vec c:\Projects\AdaBoost2\samples.vec -bg c:\Projects\AdaBoost2\Bad.dat -numStages 16 -minhitrate 0.9 -maxFalseAlarmRate 0.4 -numPos 1000 -numNeg 1821 -w 100 -h 70 -mode ALL -precalValBufSize 512 -PrecalcIdxBufSize 512
```

При выполнении следующей команды сначала вылетает следующее сообщение:

> Training parameter are loaded from the parameter file in data folder!
>
> Please empty the data folder if you want to use your own set of
>   parameters.

А затем программа завершается с ошибкой.
Папка которая указана в Data пустая.

Comment: Ваш вопрос недостаточно информативен, чтобы определить причину возникновения ошибки. Приведите, хотя бы, текст сообщения, который должен выводиться в консоли.